# Is there integration for CiviContribute Partial Payments

Tags: civicontribute, civipledge

I like using pending transactions and then recording partial payments under the contribution instead of using pledges and payments the reasons are as follows:
1. civi contribute is much more used and therefore better developed and has better integration with drupal views etc.
2. I am dealing with many dedications that are set amounts and many people pay them in installments and many pay the full amount in once. I would like to go to one place to see data on both (I can create a pledge for every donation even if its paid all in once, and look at pledge data but that's annoying. and does not work well with views)

the problems with partial payments are as follows:
1. Most of the contribution reports don't deal with the actual partial payments but just with the main contribution
 
2. thank you letters only look at the entire contribution and not the partial payments
3.any reports don't look at the dates of the actual payments but just look at the "date received" of the main contribution contribution 
4. if you make a mistake in a partial payment and record the wrong amount or the full amount due there is no way to delete a partial payment

if anyone has any advice please let me know

Comment: Hello, did you found a solution within CiviContribute? I have the same issue here.

Comment: @wintermoor there is a plugin that lets you search partial payments but in general civicrm is not complete at all in this area (and many other areas as well)
would be nice if they got basic contribution under control (similar to Quickbooks or any accounting software that just works for the many basic real world scenarios)